Making text appear next to a table without going to the next paragraph
I am designing an exam paper and I have a question. I have a table where answers must be kept (image below; the details of the table are hidden for the improbable chance one of the test-takers happen to come across this forum question).
To conserve space, I want the text to appear by the side of the table. I am aware one solution is just dividing the text as multiple lines and have them as "columns" inside the table, but I am hoping if there is an alternative. (See gray "Text" as an illustration of what I mean).

Here is the code of the fbox (the actual text is replaced with "Placeholder" to conserve secrecy!)
%preamble if necessary
\documentclass{exam}[a4paper]
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}

\geometry{
a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=30mm,
}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
   \gdef\rowfonttype{#1}#1%
}

%a bunch of stuff in-between

\noindent\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\vskip0.2cm

\Huge{\textsc{2.3 (2 Points)}} \vskip0.2cm

\Large


    \hskip0.2cm\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Placeholder} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{AA} \\
         \hline
         Placeholder&  &  &  & \\
         \hline
         Placeholder&  &  &  & \\
         \hline
         Placeholder&  &  &  & \\
         \hline
         Placeholder&  &  &  & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\vskip0.2cm\par %edit: removing these two doesn't fix the issue, see the edit in the question
\large{0.4 points per each correct row. Mark T for true and F for false. Empty cells will result in not obtaining any points for that row.}

\end{minipage}}

I apologize for any bad case of spaghetti code, I'm learning nuances in LaTeX as I design the paper, haha.
Edit: I noticed that \par appears after the table. This was originally put because of the issue that I am having. Here is what the code looks like without \par and vskip0.2cm. The text would go underneath the table anyway after a line's worth of text has been written.


your code is not complete and can't be tested.

This isn't a complete answer, but you can just put the text in a parbox of suitable width and set it next to the tabular structure.  (Don't use a table environment.)

size commands do not take an argument \Huge \textsc{2.3 (2 Points)} is \Huge{\textsc{2.3 (2 Points)}}  and makes the  rest of the document \Huge which is why you needed \Large later, better to use size commands inside a group

if you wrote text after the tabular it would be next to it but you are explictly forcing a paragraph line break  with \vskip and \par also  \large{...  should again not have the {

My apologies. I was already aware \par would do that, and the reason why I included it is that the text would go underneath the table anyway after a line's worth of text has been filled. I have edited the question to include such an image.@DavidCarlisle

I am not sure why it is not complete. Running these lines alone worked fine for me (I am working on Overleaf but using Texmaker for local work/testing) Perhaps you couldn't test it because I omitted \begin{document} and \end{document} from the written code here in the question? @UlrikeFischer

You can easily check that the posted code does not produce the output shown, it stops with the error ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Your example is not compilable, but you should try wrapfig2 and test if it suits your needs.
The following MWE shows how. It is not your code because, as I said before, it does not compile and has a lot of issues (font size commands don't work like that for example, they don't accept an argument, they should be delimited in a group), but I think you can catch how it works and adapt to your document.
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{wrapfig2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    {\Huge\textsc{2.3 (2 Points)} \vskip0.2cm}
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff \\
            \hline
            stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff \\
            stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff \\
            stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff \\
            stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}


